# Best way to encode values for SharePoint 2013 search REST api query text parameter values?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, search, rest

For SharePoint 2013 Search REST api, for the query text parameter values, what is the best way to encode all possible characters that would result in a syntax error, in javascript?

So far I came up with this:

```
    this.getSafeRestSearchValue = function(parameterValue) {
        return parameterValue.replace(/ /g, "+").replace(/'/g, "''");           
    };
```

Does anyone know if this is right and would account for all cases?

And what if the value has a `+` in it (not meant to be a space, but actually a plus sign), how would I make it not encoded?

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to use regex (Regular expresion)?

Comment: Its not the technique for replacing I'm concerned about, its more about what specific characters to replace and to replace with what.